# More properties of closure and accumulation point

Tags: general-topology

Prove: $(\overline{A\bigcap B}) = \overline{A}\bigcap \overline{B}$

proof: Let $p\in(\overline{A\bigcap B})$ be an accumulation point of the intersection. First, let's assume that $p\in A\bigcap B$, then $p\in A$ and $p\in B$. If $p\in A$, then $p\in \overline{B}$ so $p\in \overline{A}\bigcap \overline{B}$. If $p\in B$, then $p\in \overline{B}$, so $p\in \overline{A}\bigcap \overline{B}$. Therefore, $p\in \overline{A}\bigcap \overline{B}$.

I am not sure if I am right, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Actually, I have this: $\overline{A\cup B}=\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$ instead of $\overline{A\cap B}=\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$ . Maybe you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cap B\subseteq A$ so $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}$
and likewise $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{B}$ so that $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.

In general it is not true that $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cap B}$.

Counterexample: $A=\left(0,1\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\left(1,2\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}=\left[0,1\right]\cap\left[1,2\right]=\left\{ 1\right\} $
and $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{\varnothing}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. A counterexample is $A = \mathbb{Q}$, $B= \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{\emptyset} \subsetneq \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R} \cap\mathbb{R} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$$

In general, the only thing you can say is that $\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, since $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ is a closed set containing $A \cap B$.